# Eclipse output execution time after every run

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I know we can use **System.printTimeinMillis()** method at the start and end of the program. But imagine having this for every executable in the project and checking in that code in CVS.

When Junit test cases are run i see execution time of the test case as **14.662s** from the attached. When you run your program over and over making code changes its a great means to see if there is any improvement.

Is there any way(inbuilt option or plugin) i can have eclipse printing out time taken after every execution on console?

I have come across a **[plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/downloads/?ver=4.7.2)** but its not working on Eclipse Juno 4.1 version.

[image]

Comment: I think you should consider very carefully which questions you want to ask - this will most likely show you what data you need to have logged.  Then just add the few lines of code logging that data to your executables.